# How to Use Permissions in Sentry for Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I need to use Sentry 2.1 in a Laravel application, I read this document 
https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/2.1
what I really need to have is some groups and assign some permissions to each group and then assign those groups to the users.

take this as an example (which I took from the same link):
I register a user with following detaiks

```
 Sentry::register(array(
   'email'    => 'john.doe@example.com',
   'password' => 'foobar', 
   'activated' => true,    
));
```

Then I register a group with the following details:

```
 $group = Sentry::createGroup(array(
    'name'        => 'Moderator',
    'permissions' => array(
        'admin' => 1,
        'writers' => 1,
    ),
));
```

And then I assigned the group to the user

The Question:
Can someone provide me with a piece of code  that helped me through how  I should modify `routes.php` and add filters to it, so that the filters will apply on permissions and not the groups.

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'admin'), function()
{
    Route::controller('admin','adminController');

});

Route::group(array('before' => 'mod'), function()
{
     Route::controller('cruds','crudController');
 });
```

For example users with `admin` permissions can only see the adminController links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking permissions is done via the Sentry `hasAccess()` method. You can either create multiple filters to take specific actions for different permission checks, or you can use a generic filter which takes the permission as a parameter and check on that. Below is a generic "hasAccess" filter, to which you pass the permission for which to check.

Filter:

```
Route::filter('hasAccess', function ($route, $request, $value) {
    try {
        // get the logged in user
        $user = Sentry::getUser();

        // check the user against the requested permission
        if (!$user->hasAccess($value)) {
            // action to take if the user doesn't have permission
            return Redirect::home();
        }
    } catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException $e) {
        // action to take if the user is not logged in
        return Redirect::guest(route('login'));
    }
});
```

Routes:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'hasAccess:admin'), function() {
    Route::controller('admin','adminController');
});

Route::group(array('before' => 'hasAccess:mod'), function() {
    Route::controller('cruds','crudController');
});
```